# Need a LINQ statement from SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have this SQL statement

```
Use [Project]
select [TableName] = OBJECT_NAME(object_id), last_user_update
From sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
Where database_id = DB_ID('Project')
and OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('Employee')
```

this query returns a table name and the time that it was last updated. I am trying to use this query in an MVC project as a LINQ statement.

Comment: LINQ is a technology and question needs pointing to concrete LINQ provider (EF, EF Core,  linq2db, LINQ to SQL, NHibernate). Anyway you cannot do that with most of the mentioned LINQ providers, except `linq2db`.

Comment: Have you attempted to create any part of the LINQ statement yet?  Do you have the beginnings of one or are you not sure where to start?

Comment: Are you expecting to return a single value or a list of table names?

Comment: It should return the table but with an extra column that states when it was last updated.

Comment: since you have the sql query. Why don't you use EF to sql query. e.g.   IEnumerable<yourviewmodel> result = db.Database.SqlQuery<yourviewmodel>(yourquery);